# Python script to compare sql tables created once a day with updated data

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a script that gets data from an API once a day (every 24 hours) and this data is written into a database (test.db).

A new table name is created each 24 hours with the name of table saved as "table" + round(datetime.timestamp(now)

so table names will be similar to table1616851858 for example. I will have several of these table names with a timestamp for each day.

I now need another script to read the database (test.db) and compare the last 7 day tables; and compare a field called "cost" in the table and create a new variable called average cost which provides the average of the last 7 days.

I am able to list the table names with the script below, but am not able to know how to only restrict to the last 7; and then compare and average the fields from these 7 tables.

```
import os
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
print(cursor.fetchall())
cursor.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: Why not have the date as another column in your table? That way you'd only have one table and querying by dates would be much simpler.

Comment: The tables has other columns with data that would also change each time the API is called. As first step I am only comparing one field against last 7 day tables; but will have to do more eventually. If I right it in another column, then I will have to do all columns.

Comment: I was not suggesting you combine totally different table structures into one table. E.g., if you have a product table and a sales table, then keep those separate but do not have, e.g., product1616851858, product1616938258, etc., and the same for sales. I.e., you'll have just one product table with a date column and a sales table also with its own date column.